# Remove buffer from polygon

Tags: arcgis-pro, buffer, remove

I need to remove the outside area of a polygon based on a numerical value in a python script.  It would be to determine a core habitat for a species that don't live at the edge of their habitat.  I'm at a total loss on how to approach this.

My ultimate goal is to create a tool in ArcGIS pro, but I need to develop the script first.

Comment: I think buffer tool did accept negative value, did you try that ?

Comment: No, I'll have to give it a try.  I didn't even think of that.  Thanks.

Comment: If for some reason the buffer tool doesn't accept a negative value, you can convert the polygon boundary to a line, buffer the line, and use that buffer to clip the polygon.

Comment: I was sidetracked for the past 2 days, but I'll try that if the negative number doesn't work.  Thx